# How to get multiple values out of resolve() and reject()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, https

I would like both `resolve()` to return `{valid_to: cert.valid_to, statusCode, statusMessage}` and `reject()` should return `{error: -1, statusCode, statusMessage}`.

**Question**

How can I do that, when `statusCode`, `statusMessage` are in a different scope?

```
const https = require('https');

(async () => {
  const options = {
    hostname: "github.com",
    port: 443,
    path: '/',
    method: 'GET',
    timeout: 1000
  };

  options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
  let valid_to = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const req = https.request({
      ...options, checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
        resolve(cert.valid_to);
      }
    }).on('error', error => {
      reject(-2);
    });

    req.on("timeout", chunk => {
      reject(-1);
    });

    req.on('response', response => {
      console.log(response.statusCode);
      console.log(response.statusMessage);
    });

    req.end();
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    return -3;
  });

})();
```

Comment: Save the certificate in a variable (since checkServerIdentity will happen first, before response) and resolve the promise in the response callback with all 3 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will do something like this.

Edit: You need to specify `res.on('data')` in the `https.request` Object. Otherwise, timeout will always emit because there is no activity from the stream.

You can resolve in `res.on("data")` or `res.on("end")` and it is up to your use case.

`res` is [an IncomingMessage object is created by http.ClientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpincomingmessage) and passed as the first argument to the 'request' and 'response' event respectively.

`req` is [A reference to the original http.ClientRequest](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#class-httpclientrequest).

Both streams can emit events and you may handle them separately.

Also, when you reject the Promise, you actually cannot get the statusCode and StatusMessage from the `req` because there is an error in the `req` and the `.on("response")` will not be emitted. So, you need to customize the `statusCode` and `statusMessage` yourself.

```js
const https = require("https");

// {valid_to: cert.valid_to, statusCode, statusMessage}
// {error: -1, statusCode, statusMessage}.

(async () => {
    const options = {
        hostname: "githubasdfa.com",
        port: 443,
        path: "/",
        method: "GET",
        timeout: 1000,
    };

    options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
    try {
        const response = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let valid_to;
            let statusCode;
            let statusMessage;
            const req = https
                .request(
                    {
                        ...options,
                        checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
                            valid_to = cert.valid_to;
                        },
                    },
                    res => {
                        res.on("data", chunk => {
                            resolve({
                                valid_to,
                                statusCode,
                                statusMessage,
                            });
                        });

                        res.on("end", () => {
                            console.log("No more data in response.");
                        });
                    }
                )
                .on("error", err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    reject({
                        error: -2,
                        statusCode: "custom code",
                        statusMessage: "unhandled error",
                    });
                })
                .on("timeout", chunk => {
                    reject({
                        error: -1,
                        statusCode: "custom code",
                        statusMessage: "unhandled error",
                    });
                })
                .on("response", response => {
                    statusCode = response.statusCode;
                    statusMessage = response.statusMessage;
                })
                .end();
        });

        console.log(response);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
})();
```

Comment: When I run it, it always fails with `-1`. Can you get it to resolve?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting, set your timeout bigger. like 10000 (10secs)? I updated my answer because of some bug.

Comment: Same problem. Still gives `-1`. With the original code it works for `1000`.

Comment: `statusCode`, `statusMessage` are also not being set.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting, I add more explanation and updated some codes to be more clearer.

Comment: Very nice. Thanks =) I see you have used `.on()` instead of `res.on()`. Is it a matter of taste or do that different things?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting, just matter of taste. `res.on().on();` and `res.on(); res.on();`

Comment: Great to know, as I see both often =) Btw. isn't the try/catch you are using only for synchronously code? I would have expected `.catch(err => {})`. ?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting, also work with async function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#adding_error_handling

Comment: Ok, very interesting! Thanks for sharing =)